# PHP: RegEx for string with 3-9 letters and 5-50 numbers

Tags: php, regex

How can I make a RegEx in PHP that only accepts 3-9 letters (uppercase) and 5-50 numbers?

I'm not that good at regular expressions. But this one doesn't work:

```
/[A-Z]{3,9}[0-9]{5,50}/
```

For instance, it matches `ABC12345` but not `A12345BC`

Any ideas?

Comment: So `1A2B3C4D5` is valid?

Comment: Define `doesn't work`. You keep saying that but you never really tell what you mean. It's also preferable to provide some input and the expected output. That said, I'm going to close this question as "unclear". Please edit your question

Comment: Added a variation in case you're interested. Cheers.

Comment: @HamZa FYI, added a quick edit to the question to clarify what didn't work for Treps. Over and out, see you next time. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a classic "password validation"-type problem. For this, the "rough recipe" is to check each condition with a lookahead, then we match everything.

```
^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3,9}[^A-Z]*$)(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){5,50}[^0-9]*$)[A-Z0-9]*$
```

I'll explain this one below, but here's a variation that I'll leave for you to figure out.

```
^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3,9}[0-9]*$)(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){5,50}[A-Z]*$).*$
```

Let's look at the first regex piece by piece.

1. We anchor the regex between the head of string ^ and end of string $ assertions, ensuring that the match (if any) is the whole string.
2. We have two lookaheads: one for the capital letters, one for the digits.
3. After the lookaheads, `[A-Z0-9]*` matches the whole string (if it consists only of uppercase ASCII letters and digits). (Thanks to @TimPietzcker for pointing out that I was asleep at the wheel for starting out with a dot-star there.)

**How do the lookaheads work?**

The `(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3,9}[^A-Z]*$)` asserts that at the current position, i.e. the beginning of the string, we are able to match "any number of characters that are not capital letters, followed by a single capital letter", 3 to 9 times. This ensures we have enough capital letters. Note that the `{3,9}` is greedy, so we will match as many capital letters as possible. But we don't want to match more than we wish to allow, so after the expression quantifies by `{3,9}`, the lookahead checks that we can match "zero or any number" of characters that are not a capital letter, until the end of the string, marked by the anchor `$`.

The second lookahead works in similar fashion.

For a more in-depth explanation of this technique, you may want to peruse the password validation section of this page about [regex lookarounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

In case you are interested, here is a token-by-token explanation of the technique.

```
^                      the beginning of the string
(?=                    look ahead to see if there is:
 (?:                   group, but do not capture (between 3 and 9 times)
  [^A-Z]*              any character except: 'A' to 'Z' (0 or more times)
   [A-Z]               any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
 ){3,9}                end of grouping
  [^A-Z]*              any character except: 'A' to 'Z' (0 or more times)
$                      before an optional \n, and the end of the string
)                      end of look-ahead
(?=                    look ahead to see if there is:
 (?:                   group, but do not capture (between 5 and 50 times)
  [^0-9]*              any character except: '0' to '9' (0 or more times)
   [0-9]               any character of: '0' to '9'
 ){5,50}               end of grouping
  [^0-9]*              any character except: '0' to '9' (0 or more times)
$                      before an optional \n, and the end of the string
)                      end of look-ahead
[A-Z0-9]*              any character of: 'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9' (0 or more times)
$                      before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: What's the reason for the lookaheads? Wouldn't the regex in the question work just by adding start and end of line characters?

Comment: @billyonecan The lookaheads are necessary to ensure that we have the right number of each kind of character. If they appeared sequentially (first the CAPS then the dig1ts), we could do away with the lookaheads. That's probably what you had in mind, right?

Comment: @zx81 ahh that makes sense! I didn't realise OP needed to match those characters non-sequentially

Answer (score 4):

Is this your problem? http://regexr.com/38pn0

If so, you need to anchor the expression to the start and end of the string:

```
/^[A-Z]{3,9}[0-9]{5,50}$/
```

See, the result: http://regexr.com/38pmt (no match)

Comment: What about this string: `A305BC14` It is three uppercase characters and five numbers?!

Comment: So, are you saying that you don't want them grouped?

Comment: I think the question's owner did not determine that.

Comment: This is perfect if you understand the question to mean that we want to match sequentially, i.e. all the caps first, then all the digits. Upvoting your answer for this valid interpretation. :)