# Matches a string containing two variables using a regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to match a string that has the following requirements:

- The string contains 5 to 10 digits. [0-9]
- Contains 2 to 3 letters. [a-z]

for example

- 123a2bc12
- s123d456

This is my regular expression. /^\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z]?\d*$/. But this can only limit the number of letters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you tell us what you've tried, and how it's behavior is different than what you're expecting?

Comment: I disagree with @zerkms. We don't know the full impact of this maneuver. Maybe best to hold off for now.

Comment: This is my regular expression. `/^\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z]?\d*$/`. But this can only limit the number of letters. @alexanderbird

Comment: Thanks! Can you edit that into the question? See [help:how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ("Help others reproduce the problem")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't pretty but this should be what you're looking for:

```
^(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2,3}[0-9]*$)(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){5,10}[A-Za-z]*$).*$
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This regular expression can work.I'm not familiar with regular expressions, and I would be very grateful if you could explain this regular expression.

Comment: I did a little digging to help me out.  This is what you should read.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426162/php-regex-for-string-with-3-9-letters-and-5-50-numbers @JKol Hope it all helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to this

```
s=re.search(r'(\w+)','123a2bc12').group(1)
print s   #The output is '123a2bc12'
```

Comment: This method is good, but it doesn't limit the number of letters and Numbers in a string.

Comment: sorry,I don't  understand very well.